# cannot load video or image on visual studio 2015+opencv3

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I install opencv 3 on visual studio 2015 follow exactly google. First I build Opencv + Opencv_contrib + cmake use visual studio 2015. After that i install it into visual and i do exactly step by step follow tutorial in google include:

1)add path into Evironment Variables

2)C/C++ >> general >> Additional Include Directory = C:\opencv\build\install\include

3)Linker >> General >> Additional Library Directories = c:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc14\lib

4)Linker >> input >> Additional Dependencies = opencv_core331d.lib + ... +

And finaly i make a example to test

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace cv;

using namespace std;
int main() {

    cv::Mat frame = cv::imread("iphone.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("test", frame);
    system("pause");
}
```

instead of it will slow the image, but dont. The result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvdoF.png)

And i dont know what I wrong or mistake

please help me. Any idea will appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what `system("pause")` does. The common practice for OpenCV is to put `waitKey(0)` instead of `system("pause")`.

Comment: thanks, i find the solution that i miss config in VC++ Directories. Any way thanks for your anwser.